# setting seed locally (not globally) in R

Tags: r, global, local, seeding

I'd like to set seeds in R only locally (inside functions), but it seems that R sets seeds not only locally, but also globally. Here's a simple example of what I'm trying (not) to do.

```
myfunction <- function () {
  set.seed(2)
}

# now, whenever I run the two commands below I'll get the same answer
myfunction()
runif(1)
```

So, my questions are: why does R set the seed globally and not only inside my function? And how I can make R to set the seed only inside my function?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Something like this does it for me:

```
myfunction <- function () {
  old <- .Random.seed
  set.seed(2)
  res <- runif(1)
  .Random.seed <<- old
  res
}
```

Or perhaps more elegantly:

```
myfunction <- function () {
  old <- .Random.seed
  on.exit( { .Random.seed <<- old } )
  set.seed(2)
  runif(1)
}
```

For example:

```
> myfunction()
[1] 0.1848823
> runif(1)
[1] 0.3472722
> myfunction()
[1] 0.1848823
> runif(1)
[1] 0.4887732
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try your answer. Any idea why R has this unexpected (at least to me) side effect?

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. @ManoelGaldino As to "why?" I don't think this is unexpected at all. Implementing a new, separate random generator for every function environment would be terribly complicated, I would think. And possibly carry some performance overhead.

Comment: I do think someone with greater knowledge than I should comment about how this issue affect parallel processes.

Comment: There's a small problem with this answer. Object `.Random.seed` may not exist if the seed has not been set or `runif()` (or other functions accessing the random number generator) has not been called in the current R session. Thus before storing `.Random.seed` one needs to check its existence with `exists()`, and maybe invoke runif() if it doesn't.

Comment: @TheodoreLytras In an ideal world, `set.seed` would return the old value of the seed.

Comment: That's an excellent answer. One question, won't **`<<--`** always push to parent frame? Shouldn't we use `assign` with `envir = globalenv` to ensure that `old` is pushed back to the global environment?

Comment: How about `on.exit(set.seed(NULL))`? Then you don't need to store the old value?

Answer (score 1):

Using @Romain Francois's answer, generalize as function:

```
withRandom <- function(expr, seed = 1) {
    old <- .Random.seed
    on.exit({.Random.seed <<- old})
    set.seed(seed)
    expr
}
```

Usage:

```
runif(2)
withRandom(seed = 2, {
    runif(1)
    runif(1)
})
runif(2)
withRandom(seed = 2, runif(2))
runif(2)
```

output:

```
> runif(2)
[1] 0.5776099 0.6309793
> withRandom(seed = 2, {
+     runif(1)
+     runif(1)
+ })
[1] 0.702374
> runif(2)
[1] 0.5120159 0.5050239
> withRandom(seed = 2, runif(2))
[1] 0.1848823 0.7023740
> runif(2)
[1] 0.5340354 0.5572494
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the seed locally for a chunk of code you can use the `with_seed` function from the `withr` package:

```r
withr::with_seed(123, {
  runif(1) # this always gives the same number
})
runif(1)   # this one is different every time
```