# Set R graphics parameters locally but not globally?

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to set or mask `par()` in a local environment? I'm not terribly familiar with R environments so I'm not clear on why this wouldn't be possible, although I definitely understand why it isn't the default behavior. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324096/setting-seed-locally-not-globally-in-r) but I don't know enough to know whether it applies here. I'd also be surprised if there isn't some way to tweak the search path to get it to work.

Then again, there's no way to tweak the algorithm that decides whether to omit some of your axis labels... would it be so hard to just have a switch to turn the feature off and let users pay the price? That seems to have been the design philosophy for everything else in the language (and I'm kind of starting to appreciate it).

Comment: You can pass any `par` parameters in the `plot` function.

Comment: Minor caveat to what @SimonO'Hanlon said, there are a handful, listed at the beginning of `?par` that can only be set by calling `par` directly. But the vast majority can be handled by `plot` directly.

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. RTFM I guess. But I also should have specified that I was thinking about stuff like `mfrow` and `layout`, as well as situations where I'd like to change `mar` for several plots at a time. I feel like calling some of these functions repeatedly would just make the code even harder to read, or again wouldn't be possible. It would be nice to just type `local({ ... }, envir)` and fill `...` with a bunch of par changes commands that I don't have to worry about undoing later. Would be easier to experiment as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answer(s) and comments, note that graphical parameters are local to the graphics device, so you can open a new graphics device, set the parameters you want, then when you are through close the device (or switch back to the other one) and the previous parameters will be in effect.  A quick example:

```
dev.new()
par(col='blue')
hist(rnorm(100))
abline(v=0, lwd=5)
dev.new()
par(col='red')
hist(rnorm(1000))
par(lwd=5)
abline(v=0)
dev.off()
plot(runif(25), rnorm(25))
abline(h=0, lwd=3)
```

See the help for `dev.list` and `dev.set` for details on switching between graphics devices.

Comment: So if I just use `windows()` all the time (like I do anyway) it shouldn't even matter? Or is `dev.new()` fundamentally different from `windows()`? The docs for one say nothing about the other.

Comment: The `dev.new` function is the cross platform way to open a new device.  On Windows it calls the `windows` function, but on other OSs it calls an appropriate function for that OS.  So if your code will run only on windows, then the `windows` function is fine and will do the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

As commented above, you can pass `par` parameters in the `plot` function, but this doesn't alway work for contributed plotting functions (and not all parameters work this way -- see `?par`).  Another useful idiom for restricting parameter changes to the body of a function is

```
function(...) {
    old.pars <- par(...,no.readonly=TRUE)
    on.exit(par(old.pars)))
    ...
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that this idiom is safe if you break out of a function in a non-standard way (e.g. Ctrl-C while the function is running, or debugging/Q, rather than a usual `return()`)

I have encountered a few functions within contributed packages that modify the global `par` settings without resetting them, which I consider very bad practice ...

Comment: I've found it's also nice to give users an option *not* to restore par settings in case they want to use lines() or something to add to the plot you just made. `if(reset.par) on.exit(par(old.pars)))`

Comment: So the point is there's no actual way to mask `par()`? Bummer. I guess it's time to, y'know, start writing functions instead of top-level scripts...

Comment: `on.exit()` is 100% safe. But it's best to get in the habit of using `add = TRUE` otherwise you'll one day accidentally overwrite a previous `on.exit()` and spend hours tearing your hair out trying to find the problem.